# git-add dir recursively but obeying gitignore

Tags: git, msysgit

im using git with java so i have deeply nested directories. to add a pattern to git recursively, I am using:

```
find . -iname "*.xml" | xargs git add
```

which detects ignored directories like 'bin' and aborts (because the shell expands my wildcard, not git)

what is a better way?

http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=141

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hadn't found `git add -A` which does what i need

Answer (score 5):

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard -o | grep '\.xml$'
```

Comment: +1. But it seems that `git ls-files` accepts globs as filename option and grep is not needed. It's also not clear if Dustin wants to apply `git add` on untacked files only.